# R - Pass a string to a formula for dataframe subset

Tags: r, string, function

I have a dataframe called `returns` with different columns, for instance `simple`. I normally access it by `returns$simple`. Now I need to pass these columns on to a function. I tried many things that I found here on the board (`as.formula`, `parse`, `paste`, etc.) and none of it worked.

```
test = function(x) 
{ 
  returns$x
}
test(simple)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could access your columns using the bracket notation. Here's how you do it:

```
test = function(x) 
{ 
    returns[,x]
}
test("simple")
```

Or simply (without using a function):

```
returns[, column_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
returns[,x]                    # a
```

or get column id, using which.

```
which(names(returns)==x)       # b
```

Another idea is to use grep

```
grep("^x$", colnames(returns)) # c
grep("^x$", names(returns))    # d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[[` to values in the column based on the name of the column. If you don't want to quote the name of the column when calling the function, you have to use `deparse` and `substitute`.

```
test <- function(x) 
{ 
  xc <- deparse(substitute(x))
  returns[[xc]]
}

test(simple)
```